# warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default] and cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

Tags: c

when i try to run my code, there got warning and i don't know why....Please help me, this is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/time.h>

#define TESTTIMES 2000


void test1()
{
    // printf("--------TEST1----------\n");
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
        char *p = (char*)MyMalloc(1);
        MyFree(p);
    }
}


void test2()
{
    // printf("--------TEST2----------\n");
    int *a[150], i;
    for (i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
        char *p = (char*)MyMalloc(1);
        a[i] = p;
        if ((i + 1) % 50 == 0) {
            int j = i + 1  - 50;
            while (j <= i) {
                MyFree(a[j]);
                j += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

void test3()
{
    // printf("--------TEST3----------\n");
    int flag, cnt = 0, top = 0;
    char *b[50];

    srand(time(NULL));
    while(cnt < 50) {
        flag = rand() % 2;
        if (flag) {
            char *p = (char*)MyMalloc(1);
            b[top] = p;
            top++;
            cnt += 1;
        } else {
            if (top > 0) {
                top -= 1;
                MyFree(b[top]);
            }
        }
    }
    while (top > 0) {
        top--;
        MyFree(b[top]);
    }
}

void test4() 
{
    // printf("--------TEST4----------\n");
    int flag, size, cnt = 0, top = 0;
    char *b[50];

    srand(time(NULL));
    while(cnt < 50) {
        flag = rand() % 2;
        size = rand() % 64 + 1;
        if (flag) {
            char *p = (char*)MyMalloc(size);
            b[top] = p;
            top++;
            cnt += 1;
        } else {
            if (top > 0) {
                top -= 1;
                MyFree(b[top]);
            }
        }
    }
    while (top > 0) {
        top--;
        MyFree(b[top]);
    }
}

void test5()
{
    // printf("--------TEST5----------\n");
    int i = 0;
    while (i < TESTTIMES) {
        char *p = MyMalloc(4096);
        MyFree(p);
        i++;
    }
}

void test6()
{
    // printf("--------TEST6----------\n");

    int top = 0, i = 0;
    char *b[100];

    while(1) {
        char *p = (char*)MyMalloc(100); 
        if (p) {
            b[top] = p;
            top++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    while(i < top){
        MyFree(b[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

and I got warning on these lines:

```
ind.c: In function \u2018test1\u2019:
ind.c:79:19: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
         char *p = (char*)MyMalloc(1);
                   ^
ind.c: In function \u2018test2\u2019:
ind.c:90:19: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
         char *p = (char*)MyMalloc(1);
                   ^
ind.c:91:14: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
         a[i] = p;
              ^
ind.c: In function \u2018test3\u2019:
ind.c:112:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
             char *p = (char*)MyMalloc(1);
                       ^
ind.c: In function \u2018test4\u2019:
ind.c:140:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
             char *p = (char*)MyMalloc(size);
                       ^
ind.c: In function \u2018test5\u2019:
ind.c:162:19: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
         char *p = MyMalloc(4096);
                   ^
ind.c: In function \u2018test6\u2019:
ind.c:176:19: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
         char *p = (char*)MyMalloc(100); 
                   ^
```

is it because of different GCC version? How can I fix it? It is C programming, I got two warnings such as warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default] and cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast].

Comment: What is `MyMalloc`?

Comment: it is another c file, I have mymalloc.c and mymalloc.h, and i tried to use make to run this.

Comment: You don't include `mymalloc.h`.

Comment: i included mymalloc.h in mymalloc.c, this file is memgrind.c ,this file with my memory test and profiling code as described above. so three files: mymalloc.c,mymalloc.h and memgrind.c. and i have a makefile have memgrind:
 gcc -g -O0 memgrind.c mymalloc.c -o memgrind 2>log.txt

Comment: Where is the definition of `MyMalloc` function?
`MyMalloc` in yours may return a value with size lower than pointer. Let's say it returns `int` which is 4 bytes and your system is 64 bit then the pointer must be 8 bytes. So the warning occurs there.

Comment: But you don't include it in your main file.

Comment: i uploaded the definition of Mymalloc function which is mymalloc.h

Comment: i still get error when i include mymalloc.h in memgrind.c, it showed that:  memgrind.c: In function \u2018test2\u2019:
memgrind.c:91:14: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
         a[i] = p;
              ^
/tmp/cco1qVt1.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `buffer'
/tmp/ccf0ZQmO.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Well, if you have `char memory[4096]` or `struct node *buffer` variable definition in a header, and you include that header from two files, the variable will be defined twice. You can't have a variable with external linkage defined twice.

Comment: yeah, I am only including it in mymalloc.c. so how can i fix these two warning?

Comment: Near the top of `ind.c`, `#include "mymalloc.h"`.  Otherwise the compiler doesn't know what those functions look like when it's compiling that file.

Comment: ind.c is memgrind.c file i just deleted the 'memgr' when i uploaded this question. I have already used #include "mymallc.h" in the top of the mymallc.c file, if I add one more in memgrind.c , the variable will be defined twice.

Comment: What is the return type of MyMalloc()? It should be `void *`.  It should be declared as such in mymalloc.h, and you need to #include mymalloc.h in your main .c program file.

Comment: i uploaded mymalloc.h up there, i wrote : void *MyMalloc(size_t nbytes);

Comment: and i uploaded mymalloc.c file on there too

Comment: you should not do `#define malloc`, imagine if someone includes mymalloc.h and then stdlib.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting these errors:

> warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size

Is because your main file doesn't know how `MyMalloc` is defined, so it defaults to a function returning an `int`.  You can fix this by putting `#include "mymalloc.h"` at the top of your main file.

If you do this, you'll see another error, specifically that `buffer` and `memory` are defined twice.  This is because you're defining these two variables in your header file.  It is for this reason that variables shouldn't be defined in a header file.

Since you only use `buffer` and `memory` in mymalloc.c, you should move them into that file.  That way you avoid the multiple definition error.  You should also move `struct node` for the same reason.

Comment: thank u, i just move memory and struct node to memgrind.c, and it has only one warning that in function "test2" , warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
         a[i] = p;

Comment: @galaboomboom `a[i]` is an `int *` and you're trying to assign a `char *` to it.  The types need to match.